# fetching contents of a JSON Stream

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Working on a bot in Node.js which expands on the data created by another bot. That Bot outputs all it's data to a JSON page https://mee6.xyz/levels/267482689529970698?json=1

But I can't see the console output of data produced by JSONStream.
How can I get it so i can use it for my extension system?

```
var request = require('request')
  , JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
  , es = require('event-stream')

request({url: 'https://mee6.xyz/levels/267482689529970698?json=1'})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.error(data)
var stream = JSONStream.parse(['rows', true, 'doc']) //rows, ANYTHING, doc

stream.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('received:', data);
});
//emits anything from _before_ the first match
stream.on('header', function (data) {
  console.log('header:', data) // => {"total_rows":129,"offset":0}
})
  }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.
It seems that you have mixed 2 approaches described in JSONStream documentation.

First, the JSON you're requesting simply doesn't contain any fields with the name 'row' that is why this doesn't work: `.pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))`

To see the output you can do something like this:

```js
request({url: 'https://mee6.xyz/levels/267482689529970698?json=1'})
 //So I'm getting all the players records
 .pipe(JSONStream.parse('players.*'))
 .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
 }));
```

Checkout JSONStream and [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) docs.

The second is that this stream `stream = JSONStream.parse(['rows', true, 'doc'])` is created and then simply lost. You're note using it.
So if you don't like the 1st way you can do:

```js
var stream = JSONStream.parse(['players']);
stream.on('data', function(data) {
 console.log('received:', data);
});

stream.on('header', function (data) {
 console.log('header:', data);
});

//Pipe your request into created json stream
request({url: 'https://mee6.xyz/levels/267482689529970698?json=1'})
 .pipe(stream);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the first one was perfect, yeah i figured i was making a stupid error somewhere. i changed the last line to console.log(data.name); and that just output the player name, just need to find a way to sort them so i can so a comparison of data.id to its match in my database.id.
Going to keep tinkering to see if can sort them into an array or or smething. thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. Being New to backpressure its been really hard to figure out an easy way for a good Flow. Been fighting with dying streaming charts for 3 days straight and this fixed it. Testing it on a huuuge dataset now.